# How to dismiss progressdialog if mp3 is already playing in android

Tags: android

My question is how do you dismiss the ProgressDialog if mp3 is already playing?

Please check what I have tried so far:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(timelessFuture);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); 

// gets the song length in milliseconds from URL
mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); 
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Downloading", "Please wait while podcast is being downloaded...");

if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.start();
    play.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.button_pause, 0, 0, 0);
}   else {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    play.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.button_play, 0, 0, 0);
}

primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
```

What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 0):

when playing starts, use

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: What I want is like an asynctask, but I'm using mediaplayer to play an mp3 file from a url. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mediaPlayer.prepare();` you can use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();` which works asynchronously.

But then you need to implement `OnPreparedListener`to your activity or service. After that you also need to say `mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);`. So basicly when media player is ready, prepared, it goes to method below. So you can dismiss your progress dialog as like below.

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```